# I encountered a glitch

Tags: informal-language

I was at the library, and walked up to the lady behind the reference desk to tell her about the trouble I had in pulling up the E-book on my laptop the way she had told me to. How could I have said, *I've encountered a glitch* in a natural, idiomatic, or informal way? *I (was) faced (with) a glitch* is another way of saying the same thing, but is there a more informal way of saying it? Can I say, *I hit a glitch* or *I was hit by a glitch*?

Comment: What kind of glitch? Also you should add some example sentences with sufficient context to understand the situation.

Comment: From a gaming field perspective, "I faced a glitch." is natural to me.

Comment: I can think of a large number of alternative sayings. Personally, I would say *problem* rather than *glitch*, and I'd probably phrase the sentence differently, but going down that path could lead to hundreds of different answers. There's nothing wrong with anything you've said. (Except for *I was hit by a glitch*. Don't use that one . . .)

Comment: *Houston, we've had a problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit a snag, but I'm not sure you can hit a glitch, or even face one.

You find a glitch, or more formally, encounter one.

Your first thought, "I [or I've*] found [or encountered] a glitch" would seem the simplest way to get the message across.

If you want to appear less certain as to whether it's a software bug or user error, you could say
"I think I've found a glitch".

I think "glitch" works overall because it implies no distinct blame or cause, user error or software bug. It tells them there's an issue, but it's vague enough an introduction that the next step is further triage to find exact symptom & the root cause.

*I have no preference there for informal speech, take your pick.